# R Leaflet layer control fails when using clusterOptions

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

Layers control in this map work well:

```
library(leaflet)
mini_quakes <- head(quakes, 10)
mini_quakes$stations <- as.character(mini_quakes$stations)
leaflet(mini_quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(group = ~stations, # clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
  ) %>% 
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = mini_quakes$stations)
```

However, activating clusterOptions (by uncommenting `# clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()`) prevents layers control to work adequately.

How can `addLayersControl` and `clusterOptions` work together?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you aren't defining stations as a single overlay layer, this changing it to a single group name fixes the issue.

```
library(leaflet)
mini_quakes <- head(quakes, 10)
mini_quakes$stations <- as.character(mini_quakes$stations)
leaflet(mini_quakes) %>% addTiles() %>% 
  addMarkers(group = "Stations",  clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions()
  ) %>% 
  addLayersControl(overlayGroups = "Stations")
```

Comment: Your answer allows me to show/hide all markers at once. However, I need to show/hide specific stations. My sample code allows me to do this, but I need it to work even when clustering is active.

Comment: I see, I don't have a good solution then, I would guess it causes problems because multiple groups are within the same cluster.